# how to modify the attribute values of action elements in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any way to modify the attribute values of other action elements from java code in eclipse plugin.
I need to modify the state attribute of other action element from java code. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Jyoti

Comment: Are you talking about JFace Actions or Command/Handlers?

Comment: actually i am new to eclipse plugin development. please see if you can help. I need to modify the attibute value of different action element from java code.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I would say you should look seriously at the Command framework of Eclipse.

There are many different sources of information about this framework.  Just google for "[eclipse commands and handlers](https://www.google.com/webhp?output=search&q=eclipse%20commands%20and%20handlers)".

On the specifics of changing the state of a command from Java, see [Toggling a Command contribution](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/01/15/toggling-a-command-contribution/).